# How can I get content of an button in my ViewModel via RelayCommand (mvvmlight)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

i dont know how to get the Content of an Button (for examle if an button has the content "press me" i want this to have on my viewmodel as a string).

I already tried to send it via messaging service and via command parameter but it didnt work...

this is my xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="btn">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="product" Text="{Binding Artikel}" ></TextBlock>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
```

And i want the value of the button (the text of the textblock) -> "product" in my viewmodel as a string

I hope u can help me, thanks in advance!!

**EDIT:**

this is my Command binded to my Button and i have no clue how to implement the CanExecute Method...

```
 RelayCommand sendDataBtn;
    public RelayCommand SendDataBtn
    {
        get
        {
            if (sendDataBtn == null)
            {
                sendDataBtn = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    if (Globals.isLoggedIn == true) {
                      //do smth
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        var msg = new OpenOrCloseCameraPage() { Name = "open" };
                        Messenger.Default.Send<OpenOrCloseCameraPage>(msg);
                    }

                });
            }
            return sendDataBtn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "product" is not the Text of the textblock it is the name you have assigned to the textblock.  The Text is bound to the property Artikel.  Could you be clear what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to pass the `Text` of the `TextBlock` as a command parameter since you are binding to `Artikel`, but if you want to do it anyway, you could bind to the `TextBlock` like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=product}">
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="product" Text="{Binding Artikel}" ></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! and how can i get access to the CommandParameter in my VM. Sorry for asking such questions my brain isnt working anymore

Comment: @nairda-newb: It depends on your `ICommand` implementation. The `Execute` method should accept a parameter. If you are using a `RelayCommand<string>`, the method accepts a `string`.

Comment: @nairda-newb: You're welcome. Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: hey, tbh i dont understand what the sense of the Execute method is. I never had to work with it. And i never had to implement ICommand either (maybe because i always work with MVVMLight and its implemented?! ) I added some code to show you how i handle commands.

Comment: @nairda-newb: There is a generic `RelayCommand<T>` type that accepts an `Action<T>`. The non-generic `RelayCommand` doesn't accept a command parameter.